# problema al remover y agregar clase en proyecto ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

me tengo un inconveniente, resulta que trato de remover y modificar una clase, pero debo hacerlo luego de recibir la respuesta del servidor vía ajax, resulta que el servidor me entrega si, si es cliente o no, si no es cliente, si es si debo colocar una clase, y si es no debo colocar otra clase, pero únicamente me permite renombrar la clase antes de entrar al ajax, si lo coloco dentro del ajax debajo de data que es la respuesta en el ajax, no hace nada y si lo hago abajo fuera del ajax tampoco me funciona, este es el ejemplo del codigo funcionando pero esta antes de entrar al ajax, como podría hacerlo para cambiar la clase validando data.

```js
 $(document).on('click', ".btnuno", function(e)
         {
            e.preventDefault();


            let  userMessage = $("#messages").val();
            let   appendUserMessage = '<div class="chat usersMessages">'+ userMessage +'</div>';
            let boton="1";
            $("#messageDisplaySection").append(appendUserMessage);
            
            $(this).removeClass("btnuno").addClass("btndos");
           
            // ajax start
            $.ajax({
                url: "respuestas.php",
                type: "POST",
                // sending data
                data: {messageValue: userMessage,boton: boton},
                // response text
                success: function(data){


                //$("#send").addClass("btn2");
                    // show response
                    let appendBotResponse = '<div id="messagesContainer"><div class="chat botMessages">'+data+'</div></div>';
                    $("#messageDisplaySection").append(appendBotResponse);
                    
                }

            });
            

            $("#messages").val("");
            $("#send").css("display","none");
            



        });
```

Comment: Primero te recomiendo hacer un `console.log(data)` para revisar el formato que recibes en la respuesta y poder manipular la data. Luego, no será difícil hacer un condicional.

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontre el problema cambiando el $this, por el selector del id del boton al cual debo modificar, lo extraño es que con $this solo funciona desde afuera del ajax, y con el selector dentro si funciona, entonces quedo asi:

```js
 $("#send").removeClass("btnuno").addClass("btndos");
```